# How to marshal data and send on websocket?

Tags: go

Upon debugging below server side code:

```
    type myStruct struct {
        key   string
        value string
    }

    key, value := gen()
    data := myStruct{key, value}
    myJSON, err := json.Marshal(data)
    err = conn.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, myJSON)
```

---

`gen()` populates `key` and `value` with strings

`myJSON` shows:

### [image]

After writing `myJSON` on web socket, empty json is received on client side:

```
            ws.onmessage = function (evt)
            {
                console.log(evt.data)

            };
```

### [image]

Why `conn.WriteMessage()` does not transfer data(`myJSON`) to client side?

Comment: Your fields are unexported. Exported fields have first letter capitalised

Comment: @zerkms Do I need to export(`data.key` & `data.value`) for the reason that data is on wire?

Comment: Only exported fields are marshalled, regardless how you use that data. Your `myJSON` is an empty JSON object.

Comment: "Struct values encode as JSON objects. Each exported struct field becomes a member of the object, using the field name as the object key, unless the field is omitted for one of the reasons given below." https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal

Comment: "myJSON shows... len=2" - that's your empty object. Exactly what's received on the other end.

Answer (score 1):

@zerkms is right, you have to have something like this:

```
type myStruct struct {
    Key   string `json:"key"`
    Value string `json:"value"`
}

key, value := gen()
data := myStruct{Key: key, Value: value}
myJSON, err := json.Marshal(data)
if err != nil {
    // error handling
}
err = conn.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, myJSON)
if err != nil {
    // error handling
}
```

You can find simple example [here](https://github.com/cn007b/my/tree/master/ed/go/examples/websocket/src/app).